# Loop not working in head section mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, loops, razor

I'm using visual studio 11 with .Net 4.0, mvc razor 2.0

Here's my code :

```
@section head{
<script>


    function functionTest(obj, no)
    {
        var i = 0;
        while( i < 5)
        {
            console.log('test');
            i++;
        }


    }


</script>

}
```

And I got this error : `Expected "}"`

It's seems to be the loop that's causing the problem when i remove the loop and pu it directly in my _Layout.cshtml it's working.

Someone can tell me why it's not working in my section ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a known issue of the Razor 2.0 parser](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/14): it gets confused on the `<` inside a `@section`. You can verify it with changing your code to:

```
while( 5 > i)
{
   console.log('test');
   i++;
}
```

The issue state is fixed so hopefully it will work when the final release of MVC4 comes out.

Answer (score 0):

this is an infinite loop

```
while( i < 5)
    {
        console.log('test');
    }
```

try it in your browser console and you will check it

Comment: ahah yep, i've failed when i trim my code, but there's an error anyway even like my edit

Comment: I would review the js code, because the syntax is fine.
Could you add more code? maybe there is something above that is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `<text>` tag. Otherwise the javascript is interpreted as razor code.

```
@section head{
    <text>
        <script>
            function functionTest(obj, no)
            {
                var i = 0;
                while( i < 5)
                {
                    console.log('test');
                    i++;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </text>
}
```